# How to convert array output [0 0 0] to [0, 0, 0] in Python with Nearest Neighbour Algorithm?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ubuntu-14.04, nearest-neighbor

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM and using the default Python 2.7. I have a Nearest Neighbour script which is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

X = np.array([[28273, 20866, 29961, 27190, 31790, 19714, 8643, 14482, 5384],
[12343, 45634, 29961, 27130, 33790, 14714, 7633, 15483, 4484]])

knn = NearestNeighbors(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, n_neighbors=5, p=2, 
radius=1.0, warn_on_equidistant=True).fit(X)

distance, indices = knn.kneighbors(X[0])
print(indices)
```

while the script runs successfully and I get an output as well - 
`[[0 1]]` (or something similar)
the issue is that there aren't any commas separating each element in the array. I have seen similar code online and the output of the other code is like - `array([[0, 1]])` or `[[0, 1]]`
I have tried the `print(', '.join(indices))` but it throws an error -
`print(', '.join(indices))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.ndarray found`
How do I modify the script such that I get the output similar to the one mentioned above? ([0, 1])
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: have you tried `list(indices)`?

Comment: what `print(indices)` results to, a string ?

Comment: If I use list(indices), I get no output at all @Zinki

Comment: @MFHS Of course not, you still have to call print on the result after to get an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> print (indices)
>
> (prints [0 1])
>
> b = list(indices)
>
> print b
>
> (prints [0,1])

Answer (score 0):

convert that into list

```
list(indices)
```

try,

```
print indices
>>>[[0 1]]
print list(indices)
>>>[array([0, 1])]
print indices.tolist()
>>>[[0, 1]]
```

Comment: How this is going to work? and what is `arr`, please specify.

Comment: If I use list(indices), I get no output at all @MohamedThasinah

Comment: i'm not getting any error. I tried in my system. What error you are getting?

Comment: I got the output following your method. I had an additional question, how do I remove the 'array' and all the brackets from the output so that I have only `0, 1` as the output? Thanks :) @Mo

Comment: Great answer, but I do not want brackets in the output, just the elements `0, 1` (and not `[[0, 1]]`. Any way I can remove all the brackets from the output? Thanks again :)